# Interior of Set Notation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I would like to denote the interior of a set using the three letters "int". However, `$\int$` clearly doesn't work as that is the integral sign. I would like it to look similar to how "min" looks when typing `$\min$` in latex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\interior}{int}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \interior A&\\
    \exp A&\\
    \interior(A)&\\
    \exp(A)&\\
    \interior\Bigl(A\Bigr)&\\
    \exp\Bigl(A\Bigr)&
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The package https://ctan.org/pkg/amsopn is part of https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath. The manual at https://ctan.org/pkg/short-math-guide might be useful for you, for example section 3.15. It is also found on page 48 of https://ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english. A discussion on manuals is found in [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Is12Prime You are welcome.